# Pandas - Filter dataframe by group aggregates

Tags: python, pandas

The full version is that I'm trying to return a dataframe of rows where each row represents an outlier within each group. So ultimately I'm trying to filter on values that fall outside of two other values.

To simplify things here though I'll just use mean() as its the comparison that I'm struggling with.

**Example:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Group": ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
    "Sub": ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
    "Values": [1, 2, 3, 10, 20, 10, 25, 100, 75, 1500, 1600, 1800]
})
```

[image]

Then I want to group by "Group" and "Sub" to find the mean of each group:

```
df.groupby(["Group", 'Sub']).mean()
```

[image]

Then I want to use these values to filter the original dataframe. So for example, filter Rows where "Values" > group "Values".mean()

So in this example I'd be expecting to see something like this, as these are the only rows above the group mean:

[image]

I've tried comparing them directly and I get:

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects
```

So I tried .set_index(['Group', 'Sub']) and I get the same error but as far as I can tell, the labels are identical? At least they are when I check .index on both.

This seems like something that should be quite straight forward but I'm really struggling to work it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use transform you can then compare it against the original value

```
df.loc[df['Values'].gt(df.groupby(['Group','Sub'])['Values'].transform('mean'))]
```

Output

```
   Group Sub  Values
3      A   A      10
4      A   B      20
5      A   C      10
9      B   A    1500
10     B   B    1600
11     B   C    1800
```

Comment: Thanks, both solutions worked for me but ultimately I found .transform easier to work with when combining multiple conditions

Answer (score 0):

Applying filtering condition:

```
res_df = df.groupby(["Group", 'Sub'])["Values"]\
    .apply(lambda x: x[x > x.mean()]).reset_index(level=[0,1])
```

---

```
   Group Sub  Values
3      A   A      10
4      A   B      20
5      A   C      10
9      B   A    1500
10     B   B    1600
11     B   C    1800
```